# Read xml as a txt in python

Tags: python, xml

i have following code in `python` (which only load data from `txt`):

```
def main():
    f = open("text.txt", "r" ) //load txt
    a = [] // new array
    for line in f:
        a.append(line.strip()) //append line

main()
```

How can i do this with `xml file?` `f = open("myxml.xml", "r" )` doesnt work. I get error : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 4877: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Using a proper XML parser will likely make this issue go away, since the parser will read the encoding out of the file, but if you insist on reading the file yourself, simply specify the correct encoding when opening the file.

Comment: I am using `python 3.4.3`. i am working at `windows`

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the xml file format, but in which [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) your file is. Python3 assumes everything to be in [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but if you are on windows your file is probably in [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). You should use:

```
f = open("text.txt", "r", encoding="cp1252")
```

Comment: `return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2893: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Maybe try `latin-1` as encoding.

Comment: Maybe look at the file and see what it says the encoding is in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

this will sure do your job.

```
a=[]
with open('reboot.xml', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
f.closed
print a
```